# Swift UI @State does get set on the first tap

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-state, swiftui-ontapgesture

I have a simple list of for a Custom View. What needs to happen is when one of the items are selected it needs to show the detail view for that item. In my code, when I select an item for the very first time, the @Statet selectedListener does not get set so the detail view does not appear. If I keep selecting the same item that was previously selected the behaviour remains the same. However, if I select a different item, it works properly and I can come back to the previous item and view its detail view without an issue. Its such a simple thing I'm trying to do and just can't figure out what I'm may be doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

```
struct ListenersListView<Model>: View where Model: ActiveListenerViewModel {

@ObservedObject var viewModel: Model
@State var showDetail = false
@State var selectedListener: UserProfile? = nil

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack(spacing:20) {
            ForEach(viewModel.allActiveListeners) { listener in
                UserImageSection(listener: listener,
                                 subtext: listener.supportAreas)
                    .onTapGesture(perform: {
                        handleTap(listener)
                    })
            }
        }
        
    }
    .padding(.horizontal,20)
    .sheet(isPresented: $showDetail, content: {
        if let listener = selectedListener {
            ListenerDetailView(listener: listener)
        }
        else {
            // It should never come here but when the first item is selected it does. The only way to not come here is to select another item after the first item has been selected.
            Text("Listener not loaded yet")
        }
    })
    
    
}

private func handleTap(_ listener: UserProfile) {
    print("Showing listener \(listener.id)")
    self.selectedListener = listener
    showDetail = true
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS 14, in order to get the `.sheet` to be presented with up-to-date data, you must use `sheet(item:)` instead of `.sheet(isPresented:)`

You can see another one of my answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66190152/560942
and
[SwiftUI: Switch .sheet on enum, does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162219/swiftui-switch-sheet-on-enum-does-not-work/66162319#66162319)

In your specific case, it's hard to tell since I don't have your `UserProfile` code, but I suggest that you:

1. Get rid of your `showDetail` state variable
2. Make sure that `UserProfile` conforms to `Identifiable`
3. Change your `sheet(isPresented:)` to:

```
.sheet(item: $selectedListener) { listener in 
  ListenerDetailView(listener: listener)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bug in iOS 14.*

Please have a look [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652080)

When I remove optional on your **State** code, it works. So please refer this.

(I changed little bit to test on my side.)

```
@State var showDetail = false
@State var selectedListener: String = ""

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack {
            Text("Click")
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            handleTap("Handle!")
        }
    }
    .padding(.horizontal,20)
    .sheet(isPresented: $showDetail, content: {
        if let listener = selectedListener {
            Text("Get called")
        }
        else {
            // It should never come here but when the first item is selected it does. The only way to not come here is to select another item after the first item has been selected.
            Text("Listener not loaded yet")
        }
    })
}

private func handleTap(_ listener: String) {
    print("Showing listener \(listener)")
    self.selectedListener = listener
    print(self.selectedListener)
    showDetail = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hwangho but even after changing the custom Listener object to a non optional, it didn't work. The answer suggested by jnpdx works perfectly for above problem.