# Why is my Swiftui detail view not displaying the data from my tapped list item?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm building a simple app in Swiftui that stores and reads data from a Firestore collection. When a user taps on an item in the grid view, I want it to open up a detail view modal with information from that tapped item.

Currently, the modal pops up and is populated by the first item in my list only. This means that **when I tap on the second grid item**, the detail view for that tapped item is populated with the **information from the first grid item**.

Additionally, the *ontapgesture* recognizes which Habit is being tapped because it prints the correct habit.id to the console.

How can I pass the data of the grid item being tapped, to the detail view?

**Grid View**

```
struct HabitGrid: View {
   
    @EnvironmentObject var habits: Habits
    @ObservedObject var repository = HabitRepositoryViewModel()
    
    @State var isShowingHabitDetailView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        LazyVGrid(columns: layout, spacing: 10){
            
            ForEach(self.repository.habits) { habit in

                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                        VStack{

                            Text("\(habit.name)")

                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.isShowingHabitDetailView.toggle()
                            print(habit.id)
                    
                        }
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$isShowingHabitDetailView) {
                    HabitDetailView(habit: habit)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Detail View**

```
struct HabitDetailView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var repository = HabitRepositoryViewModel()
    
    var habit: Habit
    
    var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        
        
        VStack{

            Text("\(habit.name)")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This might be very basic. I appreciate any and all help! Thanks.

Comment: Switch to using `sheet(item:)` instead of `isPresented`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66287123/560942

Comment: Yes perfect, thank you