# swiftui 2.0 Image Gallery onTapgesture only shows the first image in the array

Tags: swiftui, image-gallery

I am creating a reusable gallery view for an app and am having difficulties when any picture is tapped it suppose to become full screen  but only the first picture in the array is shown every time no matter the picture tapped. Below is my code, thanks.

import SwiftUI

struct ReusableGalleryView: View {
let greenappData: GreenAppNews

```
let gridLayout: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: 3)

@State private var fullscreen = false
@State private var isPresented = false

var body: some View {
    VStack{

            ScrollView{
                LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout, spacing: 3) {
                    ForEach(greenappData.GreenAppGallery, id: \.self) { item in
                        Image(item)
                          .resizable()
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3, height: 150)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.isPresented.toggle()
                                print(" tapping number")
                                      }
                            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                                FullScreenModalView( imageFiller: item)
                            }
                          .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
    }
}
```

}

This is an example of the json data:

{
"id" : "1",
"GreenAppGallery" : [
"Picture-1",
"Picture-2",
"Picture-3",
"Picture-4",
"Picture-5",
"Picture-6",
"Picture-7",
"Picture-8",
"Picture-9",
"Picture-10"
]
},

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65480211/12299030?

Answer (score 2):

`fullScreenCover`, like `sheet` tends to create this type of behavior in iOS 14 when using `isPresented:`.

To fix it, you can change to the `fullScreenCover(item: )` form.

Not having all of your code, I'm not able to give you an *exact* version of what it'll look like, but the gist is this:

1. Remove your `isPresented` variable
2. Replace it with a `presentedItem` variable that will be an optional. Probably a datatype that is in your gallery. Note that it has to conform to `Identifiable` (meaning it has to have an `id` property).
3. Instead of toggling `isPresented`, set `presentedItem` to `item`
4. Use `fullScreenCover(item: ) { presentedItem in FullScreenModalView( imageFiller: presentedItem) }` and pass it your `presentedItem` variable
5. Move the `fullScreenCover` so that it's attached to the `ForEach` loop rather than the `Image`

Using this system, you should see it respond to the correct item.

Here's another one of my answers that covers this with `sheet`: [@State var not updated as expected in LazyVGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190082/state-var-not-updated-as-expected-in-lazyvgrid/66190152#66190152)

Comment: i tried as you instructed it did not work, i dont know if its allowed on stackoverflow to correspond by email so i can send you my code for a better understanding of my problem?

Comment: Better to create a minimal reproducible example here