# Sheet presented through a ContextMenu is missing it's data on the first try

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm having an issue presenting a `Sheet` when selecting one of the options in a `ContextMenu`. The first time that the `Sheet` is presented, it's missing the initial data. Following presentations work just fine, it's just the first one that presents the wrong behavior. Has anyone seen anything similar? I'm wondering if it's just a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

Sample code to demonstrate the issue:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var options =  ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    
    @State var modalText: String?
    @State var isShowingModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List(options, id: \.self) { option in
            Text(option).contextMenu {
                Button("Edit") {
                    // Store the option that we want to modify
                    modalText = option
                    // Trigger the modal
                    isShowingModal = true
                }
            }
        }.toolbar {
            Button {
                // Trigger the modal with no previous data because it's creation
                isShowingModal = true
            } label: {
                Text("Create")
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingModal) {
            // Reset the state, the modal might be used to edit or create
            // (create doesn't pass an initial value)
            modalText = nil
        } content: {
            Text("Edit or Create modal for \(modalText ?? "NOTHING")")
        }
    }
}
```

Video demonstrating the issue: https://twitter.com/xmollv/status/1413028616112414721

Comment: The culprit is using `sheet(isPresented:)` instead of `sheet(item:)`. `sheet(isPresented:)` always shows the *first* render of the sheet content when first presented, which is always `nil` in your case. This behavior was introduced in iOS 14 is appears often on SO. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66190152/560942 https://stackoverflow.com/a/66287123/560942 https://stackoverflow.com/a/66936503/560942 etc

Comment: @jnpdx Indeed using the `sheet(item:)` fixed the issue, thanks for pointing me to the answers! I've marked my question as duplicated, thanks everyone!

Comment: Glad I could help. If one of those answers I linked to was helpful, you could upvote it.

Comment: @jnpdx Done, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why your code does not work. But you could try this to make it work:

```
class ModalText: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var options =  ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    
    @StateObject var modalText = ModalText()
    @State var isShowingModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List(options, id: \.self) { option in
            Text(option).contextMenu {
                Button("Edit") {
                    modalText.text = option
                    isShowingModal = true
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button {
                // Trigger the modal with no previous data because it's creation
                isShowingModal = true
            } label: {
                Text("Create")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingModal) {
            // Reset the state, the modal might be used to edit or create
            // (create doesn't pass an initial value)
            modalText.text = nil
        } content: {
            Text("Edit or Create modal for \(modalText.text ?? "NOTHING")")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See my comment on the original question for an explanation of why the original code doesn't work.

Comment: yeah, I thought I tried ".sheet(item:)" and it didn't work. Maybe I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use selection parameter and it will work:

```
List(options,id: \.self, selection: $modalText) { option in
    Text(option).contextMenu {
        Button("Edit") {
            // Store the option that we want to modify
            modalText = option
            // Trigger the modal
            isShowingModal = true
        }
    }
}
```